# I can not change my app details for facebook application

Tags: facebook

I have an issue with my facebook app, I wanted to submit it to review for new permissions and the guideline is talking about submit the App Details first to review.

Here comes the problem because the App Details page has a message:

```
Editing App Info is disabled because your App Details submission is pending review. 
To make changes, please review your submission on the Status & Review page.
```

On the `Status & Review` page I do not have anything submitted to review and the app details fields are disabled.

App Details screenshots of disabled fields from which at least App icon is required:

http://screencast.com/t/sjkxHiVIX

http://screencast.com/t/h46lKzSZUl

Status & Review page:

http://screencast.com/t/9X8lGRG0zAW

If I add `App Details` as new item to review I get this error for missing banner, but banner image upload is disabled as you can see in the second screenshot.

http://screencast.com/t/1QThXh0BiUY

I am not sure what to do next and [Facebook Support page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/) is saying that Facebook engineers are around here, so if any of you is around let me know how I can fix that for the application.

Comment: You should report a bug on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs